# IntelliJ IDEA Terminal Special Characters

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, encoding, terminal, webstorm

I recently started using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate on Windows 10 and would really like to use the integrated terminal.
However, I can't get it to work with special characters like german umlauts or something like §.

That wouldn't be a problem if i hadn't some folders starting with Ü which i can't rename because they are part of a version control repo.
Because of that, i can't cd into these folders.

For example, an "ü" keystroke shows as "3R" and a "§" keystroke shows as "?" (like most special chars).

It neither works with the default terminal setting (cmd.exe) nor with git bash.

Has someone encountered a similar problem / has a solution for that?

Comment: same problem here. I cannot type ~/ to cd in home directory with cygwin. I have to type ALT + 126

Answer (score 3):

I have had similar issues with IntelliJ Ultimate on Windows 10, regarding language and encoding on the Git Bash integrated Terminal. It was solved by setting the environment variables for the integrated terminal with the correct language. It can be done as follows:

- Go to Settings
- Terminal
- Environment variables

Set two variables: `LC_ALL=YOUR_LANGUAGE.utf8;LANG="$LC_ALL"`, where **YOUR_LANGUAGE** is the language code for the desired language. I searched a little and I *think* the correct one for German Umlauts is: **de_DE.utf8**. So, the configuration line would be:
 - `LC_ALL=de_DE.utf8;LANG="$LC_ALL"`

[image: Screenshot of the configuration setting]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can set the file encoding by adding

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

to the idea64.vmoptions configuration file.