# intellij windows powershell not showing correct special characters

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to print currency symbols from different regions in IntelliJ but facing a weird issue.

While running the same code through IntelliJ run configuration everything is working fine but when I am trying to run the same code through IntelliJ terminal then facing the issue and currency symbols are printing with the weird character.

I have also checked the below links but still facing the same issue:
[IntelliJ IDEA Terminal Special Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398429/intellij-idea-terminal-special-characters)

Expected                     Actual             Region
212.00 €                     212.00 Ç           Finland
£212.00                      ú1212.00           Finland

Output

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide screenshots from `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Encodings` and `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Terminal`

Comment: Try adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` and `-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8` under `Help | Edit Custom VM Options` and restart.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov : please find attached screenshots for the same

Comment: @EgorKlepikov : I have already tried that but still facing issue

Comment: What JDK version and vendor do you use?

Comment: Also, provide the output of `locale` command executed  from the IDE terminal.

Comment: JDK 1.8 and  command ./gradlew --tests "digital.Tests.addProduct"

Comment: Please raise this issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and provide the IDE logs. (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data)